# kubectl timeout error when trying to deploy on a private GKE cluster

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubectl, private-cluster

kubectl version
WARNING: This version information is deprecated and will be replaced with the output from kubectl version --short.  Use --output=yaml|json to get the full version.
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"24", GitVersion:"v1.24.3", GitCommit:"aef86a93758dc3cb2c658dd9657ab4ad4afc21cb", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2022-07-13T14:30:46Z", GoVersion:"go1.18.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Kustomize Version: v4.5.4
Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp 172.16.0.2:443: i/o timeout

Comment: Are trying to execute that from your local computer?

Comment: No, iam trying to execute that from a virtual machine

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It was a problem with the connection between my subnet and my gke cluster